# Struct based program, Linker and multiple definitions?

Tags: c, linker-errors

Here are the files that I was given, I was told not to change either of the two. The specifications of the functions are in the header and the main.c is a shell to test the code:

#### date.h:

```
#ifndef _DateH_
#define _DateH_

typedef struct {
int month;
int day;
int year;
} date;

int is_leap_year(int the_year);

int days_in_month(int month,int leap_year);
// Recommendation: use switch statement


void input_date(date *dp);  // User input of form mm/dd/yyyy
                        // where mm, dd and yyy are integers
                        // NO PROMPT  JUST INPUT

void print_date(date d);    // Output format same as input_date's input format

int day_of_year(date d);    // Number of days since beginning of year
                        // January 1 is day 1 (not 0)

int compare_dates(date d1, date d2);
// Returns -1 if d1 earlier than d2, 0 if same date, +1 if d1 after d2

void check_age_and_birthday(date birthdate, date today);
// Output: "You are __ years old and this is your birthday\n"
//      or "You are __ years old and this is not your birthday\n"

void submit_status(date start, date end, date submit);
// Prints ""Submission not accepted - too early\n" if submit < start;
//        "Submission not accepted too - late\n" if end < submit;
//        "Submission accepted\n"  otherwise.
#endif

// Note: A year is a leap year if and only if it is divisible by 4
// and, if it is divisible by 100, it is also divisible by 400.
```

#### main.c:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  date d,bdate,today,start,end,submit;

  printf("Enter a date: ");
  input_date(&d);

  printf("\n");
  print_date(d);
  printf(" is day %d of year %d, which is ",day_of_year(d),d.year);
  if (!is_leap_year(d.year))
    printf("not ");
  printf("a leap year\n\n");

  printf("Enter your birthdate: ");
  input_date(&bdate);

  printf("Enter today's date: ");
  input_date(&today);

  printf("\n");
  check_age_and_birthday(bdate,today);

  printf("\nEnter the start date: ");
  input_date(&start);

  printf("Enter the end date: ");
  input_date(&end);

  printf("Enter the date submitted: ");
  input_date(&submit);

  printf("\n\n");
  submit_status(start,end,submit);

  return 0;
}
```

#### date.c:

```
#include "date.h"

int is_leap_year(int the_year)
{
   if (the_year % 4 == 0) {
                if (the_year % 100 == 0) {
                        if (the_year % 400 == 0) {
                                return (1);
                        }
                        else return (0);
                }
                else return (1);
        }
        else return (0);
}

int days_in_month(int month, int leap_year)
{
        switch (month) {
                case 1: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 2: {
                        if (leap_year) return (29);
                        else return (28);
                        break;
                }
                case 3: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 4: {      
                        return (30);
                        break;
                }
                case 5: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 6: {
                        return (30);
                        break;
                }
                case 7: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 8: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 9: {      
                        return (30);
                        break;
                }
                case 10: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
                case 11: {
                        return (30);
                        break;
                }
                case 12: {
                        return (31);
                        break;
                }
        }              
}

void input_date(date *dp)
{
        do
        {
             scanf("%d/%d/%d", dp->month, dp->day, dp->year);
        }
        while
             (dp->day > days_in_month(dp->month, is_leap_year(dp->year)) || dp->day < 1);
}

void print_date(date d)
{
        printf("%d/%d/%d", d.month, d.day, d.year);
}


int day_of_year(date d)
{
        int day_sum = 0;
        int i;

        if (is_leap_year(d.year))
        {
          for (i = 1; i < d.month; i++)
              {
              day_sum = day_sum + days_in_month(i, 1);
              }

        }
        else
        {
             for (i = 1; i < d.month; i++)
             {
                day_sum += days_in_month(i, 0);
             }
        }

         day_sum += d.day;

         return (day_sum);
}

void check_age_and_birthday(date birthdate, date today)
{
        int age;

        if (today.month > birthdate.month)
        {
                age = today.year - birthdate.year;
        }
        if (today.month < birthdate.month)
        {
                age = (today.year - birthdate.year) - 1;
        }
        if (today.month == birthdate.month)
        {
                if ((today.day > birthdate.day) || (today.day == birthdate.day)) {
                        age = today.year - birthdate.year;
                }
                if (today.day < birthdate.day) {
                        age = (today.year - birthdate.year) - 1;
                }
        }

        if (!compare_dates(birthdate, today))
        {
                printf ("You are %d years old and this is your birthday\n", age);
        }
        else
        {
                printf ("You are %d years old and this is not your birthday\n", age);
        }
}

 int compare_dates(date d1, date d2)
{
        if (d1.year > d2.year)
        {
                return (1);
        }
        if (d1.year < d2.year)
        {
                return (-1);
        }
        if (d1.year == d2.year)
        {
                if (d1.month > d2.month)
                {
                        return (1);
                }
                if (d1.month < d2.month)
                {
                        return (-1);
                }
                if (d1.month == d2.month)
                {
                        if (d1.day > d2.day)
                        {
                                return (1);
                        }
                        if (d1.day < d2.day)
                        {
                                return (-1);
                        }
                        if (d1.day == d2.day)
                        {
                                return (0);
                        }
                }
        }

 }

void submit_status(date start, date end, date submit)
{
        if (compare_dates(submit, start) == -1)
        {
                printf("Submission not accepted - too early\n");
        }
        if (compare_dates(submit, end) == 1)
        {
                printf("Submission not accepted - too late\n");
        }
        if ((compare_dates(submit, start) == 1) && (compare_dates(submit, end) == -1))
        {
                printf("Submission accepted\n");
        }

}
```

When I put them into a 'console application' project and build it, I get the error:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `submit_status'  
ld returned 1 exit status  
[Build Error] [DateStruct.exe] Error 1
```

If I run them in separate tabs, with no project created I get:

```
mangled line number section.  
[Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16'  
ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using Dev-C++ for this.

Comment: Please post the code, the command you used to compile it, and the error message here, not as links to another site.

Comment: @justsayinghey You can edit your question, and post the code in-line within the question. To format the code properly after pasting it in, select it and press the `{}` button; that will indent it by 4 spaces, which is how Markdown recognizes code (you can do this for your errors as well). Check the preview below your editing window to make sure it looks OK.

Comment: You might also want to mention your platform and compiler. It sounds like you're on Windows; are you using some version of MSVC?

Comment: Okay, hopefully everything is fixed. I'm using Dev-C++ and I'm writing everything in C. There's a date.h, main.c, and date.c in that giant code block. I was told to not touch date.h. and main.c

Comment: Interesting, I just created a project through Dev-C++ and added my three files and it actually compiled! Not sure what I did differently, but it compiles so that's a start I suppose. Unfortunately, when I run it, the "Enter a date" prompt comes up and once I enter it, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is crashing when you enter a date because you are passing the value of `dp->month`, `dp->day`, and `dp->year` to `scanf()`. `scanf()` needs a pointer to store the result in; in C, and integer looks like a pointer, so it happily tries to interpret the unitialized value in `dp->month` as a pointer, and crashes because it can't write there.

You want to use `&dp->month`, etc., instead.

I would recommending compiling with all warnings enabled (I don't know Dev-C++, but the GCC flags are `-Wall -Wextra`); I also recommend treating warnings on errors, so you can't accidentally ignore them, with `-Werror`. If I compile with warnings enabled, GCC tells me about the problem:

```
cc -Wall -Werror -Wextra    struct.c   -o struct
struct.c: In function ‘main’:
struct.c:13:3: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format]
struct.c:13:3: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

This example error was also from a very quick test file that I wrote up. It really helps when debugging a problem, and asking questions if you're stuck, if you try to create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem. The code you posted had a lot of extraneous bits; several header files, functions that you never actually get to, and so on. Stripping your code down into a minimal example of the problem can either help you find the problem yourself, or failing that, give an example that is much easier for other people to glance at and see the problem, without wading through a bunch of extra stuff.

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      

struct foo {                                                                                            
  int bar;                                                                                              
  int baz;                                                                                              
};                                                                                                      

int main() {                                                                                            
  struct foo x, *px;                                                                                    
  px = &x;                                                                                              

  printf("Enter bar and baz: \n");
  scanf("%d %d", px->bar, px->baz);

  printf("Got: %d %d\n", px->bar, px->baz);

  return 0;
}
```

And how to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      

struct foo {                                                                                            
  int bar;                                                                                              
  int baz;                                                                                              
};                                                                                                      

int main() {                                                                                            
  struct foo x, *px;                                                                                    
  px = &x;                                                                                              

  printf("Enter bar and baz: \n");
  scanf("%d %d", &px->bar, &px->baz);

  printf("Got: %d %d\n", px->bar, px->baz);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, Brian Campbell, you are a true hero. I cannot thank you enough right now. I've tweaked with the code a tiny bit, but everything seems to be running and it's just doing a bunch of variant test runs to smooth out the kinks from here on out. Thank you!

Comment: @justsayinghey No problem. I've expanded my answer a bit with how to debug problems like this in the future; I hope that helps too.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate any help with this type of stuff, this is all still fairly new to me and there are still a lot of growing pains for me to get through.